# IE innerHTML after clicking on link

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel-vba, and trying to get the innerHTML of an InternetExplorer Object, my problem is that after clicking on a link, the innerHTML doesn't change and stays as the first navigation.

is there a way to get the innerHTML of the next page after clicking the link?
Here is the code:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim hd As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.navigate "http://www.stormchaser.niu.edu/machine/textfcstsound.html"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set hd = ie.document

hd.all.Item("mo")(4).Checked = True
hd.all.Item("ft")(11).Checked = True

Set objInputs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each ele In objInputs
    If ele.Type = "submit" Then
        ele.Click
    End If
Next

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

hd.Links(0).Click

Range("K4") = ie.document.body.innerHTML
```

I'd really thank for any help.

Jon

Comment: have you tried to wait for ready state after the click?

Comment: yes, I tried this later, but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I got it, you're right that it's a timing issue, I found out how to catch the right second for calling the innerHTML method without freezing Excel, it gives Excel a timeout of 20 seconds waiting for the new window, otherwise it returns "failed".

here is the full code:

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.navigate "http://www.stormchaser.niu.edu/machine/textfcstsound.html"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set hd = ie.document

T1 = ie.document.Title

hd.all.Item("mo")(4).Checked = True
hd.all.Item("ft")(10).Checked = True
hd.getElementById("stn").Value = "LLBG"

Set objInputs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each ele In objInputs
    If ele.Type = "submit" Then
        ele.Click
    End If
Next

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

T2 = Now
Do While (Now < T2 + TimeValue("0:00:20")) And ie.document.Title = T1
    DoEvents
Loop

If ie.document.Title = T1 Then
    Debug.Print "failed"
    GoTo end_ext
End If

T1 = ie.document.Title

ie.document.Links(0).Click

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

T2 = Now
Do While (Now < T2 + TimeValue("0:00:20")) And ie.document.Title = T1
    DoEvents
Loop

If ie.document.Title = T1 Then
    Debug.Print "failed"
    GoTo end_ext
Else
    'Debug.Print "succeeded"
End If

Debug.Print ie.document.body.innerText

end_ext:
ie.Quit
Set hd = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
```

Comment: Great.  Every time I write one of these IE scripts I think.... there's got to be a better way... but there doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes a timing issue which I find is a very common problem in automating IE. The code is not waiting for the following page to load before executing hd.Links(0).Click so it is actually clicking a link on the old page.  I tested the following code and it seems to run fine. It is using the page title as a check if it is loaded instead of ie.ReadyState which doesn't seem to be working.

```
Sub test()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim hd As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Navigate "http://www.stormchaser.niu.edu/machine/textfcstsound.html"
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set hd = ie.Document

hd.all.Item("mo")(4).Checked = True
hd.all.Item("ft")(11).Checked = True

Set objInputs = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each ele In objInputs
    If ele.Type = "submit" Then
        ele.Click
        'Debug.Print ele.outerHTML
    End If
Next

Do While hd.Title <> "Forecast Sounding Text Output for KOKC" ' ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    'Debug.Print hd.Title, hd.Links(0)
    'DoEvents
Loop

'While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
Set hd = ie.Document
Debug.Print hd.Title, hd.Links(0)
hd.Links(0).Click

'Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'    DoEvents
'Loop
While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
Do While hd.Title <> "" ' ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Debug.Print hd.Title, hd.body.innerHTML
Range("K4") = hd.body.innerHTML
End Sub
```

I would also suggest ie.Visible for debugging. Hope that helps.

Comment: I added this code, but it runs non-stop, when I do this manually the page and the title changes instantly.

Comment: I edited the answer and put in my full code which is working.  I am manually shutting down IE between runs so a fresh instance is created each time.  Putting in the proper pauses is key.  Many times I use the Wait command for a few seconds instead of IE state.

Comment: have you tried to run it? when I tried it didn't work, I also added Application.wait as you said, but didn't help. maybe it depends on the IE version? I'm using IE 11